# Help understanding $p$ value?

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing, p-value

Say I’m analyzing whether a drug works.

My test statistic is the amount of days taken to recover.

I split a group of 100 into two, and give one the drug and the other a placebo.

So my null hypothesis is that there is no difference between both groups, and my alternate hypothesis is that the group given the real drug recovers quicker.

If I analyse the time taken to recover, repeating the process 10,000 times and plot it on a graph, using the test statistic of X bar of the control group - X bar of the drug group, I would notice an average sample mean of say 4 days. Why should this be a mean of 0? Surely on average the drug group would recover quicker?

Comment: Your question isn't clear to me at all. We have no way of knowing whether the means (x-bars) of the two groups should be different (i.e., zero or nonzero difference) since it is a hypothetical with no other information. This is what you would be trying to discern with the test. If you knew whether the difference was nonzero beforehand, you wouldn't need to carry out the test!

Comment: Also, in terms of the conclusion it doesn't really matter what the sample means are individually - you are more interested in whether they are different (i.e., group A has mean 4 and group B has mean 5).